# Bash - Retrieve data from mysql for http call

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting so would need your help. I am trying to get data from mysql database and use the parameters for a http call. For example,

```
$string = data from mysql

http://www.company.com/organizer/$string
```

How do I retrieve data from mysql and store in a string then use it for the http call? I need to execute the http url like using it in the browser.

My current codes are as:

```
#!bin/bash
$string = mysql Company<<EOFMYSQL
select name from HR;
EOFMYSQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about the following?

```
string="`mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname -e 'select * from foo;'`"
url="http://www.company.com/organizer"
url="$url/$string";
wget "$url"
```

Comment: This has two problems.  The first is that `string` will *literally* be equal to `\`mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname -e 'select * from foo;'\`` because you quoted it.  If you remove the quotes then it will do what you expect, i.e. the *output* of the command will be set to `string`.  The other issue is that using backticks `` is deprecated.  Instead use `$()`

Comment: thanks, however it works here maybe for backward compatibility, it will works fine too. That mysql command is a best guessing based on OP given statements but of cause, this would give an general idea to the OP where to proceed later.

Comment: Ya, it looks like I'm wrong about the quoting around the backticks making it literal. However, they *are* extraneous.

Comment: not really, try foo=bar baz, you will probably get an error (at least it is an error in my box). But if you double quote them, it would be fine. foo="bar baz". :-)

Comment: What I meant was they are extraneous around backticks.  I.e there is no difference between `foo="\`echo bar baz\`"` and `foo=\`echo bar baz\``

Comment: aha.. but normally it is good to play safe. For example just in case it does not work in another version or so.

Comment: True, extra quotes (generally) never hurts, but in this case the backticks themselves are providing the quoting. There isn't a POSIX compliant shell that you need them with.

Comment: @Jasonw The above code works but is it possible to post the url instead of using get? I'm not wanting to get any information back.

Comment: @Hend yes, it is possible with wget, man wget and look for --post-data :)

Comment: Oh. I just found curl so I'll use it. But any idea why it's showing error that curl couldn't resolve host 'information which is received from mysql'?

Comment: curl and wget is fine. couldn't resolve host information is another issue and you might want to start a ticket for that?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use *command substitution* via `$()`

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(mysql ...)
echo "http://www.company.com/organizer/$string"
```